# webpy 'Hello World' tutorial: webpy can't find class

Tags: firefox, web.py

When I run the example code partway through [this tutorial](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial), I don't immediately get an error, but when I go to the url(ht[break_link]tp://0.0.0.0:8080/), I get 'Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 0.0.0.0:8080.' I tried it with Chrome as well, no luck.

At one point webpy gave me an error along the lines of 'class index could not be found,' but I'm not sure what I did to get the error or how to reproduce it.

This is the file. It's the same as the tutorial I linked, just with print statements added:

```
import web

# Handle the url / with the index class.
urls = {
    '/', 'index'
}

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"
        print 'inside get'
print 'after index'

print "-------"
print globals()
print "-------"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "hi"
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    print "hello"
    app.run()
    print "last"
```

Outputs:

```
after index
-------
{'web': <module 'web' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages   \web\__init__.pyc'>, 'index': <class __main__.index at 0x0324F030>,     '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'code.py',     '__packa
ge__': None, 'urls': set(['index', '/']), '__name__': '__main__',     '__doc__': None}
-------
hi
hello
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
last
```

('last' doesn't show up until I ctrl-c out)
webpy's not noticing the index class, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it prints `http://0.0.0.0:8080/`, the webserver is running in a loop (due to call to `app.run()`) so, it won't print "last" until you kill the webserver. That's why you don't see 'last' until ctrl-c. All is working fine.

The `http://0.0.0.0:8080` simply says the webserver is listening on 'All valid IPv4 addresses' on the local machine. `0.0.0.0` isn't the real address. To access your webserver, point your browser to the real IP address.

If you're running this webserver on you local machine, you can probably use `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`, which (most always) refers to your local machine. If you're running this webserver on a remote machine, you'll need to provide its IPv4 address, or it's hostname instead of `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks, I was really confused.